# Align control to right - xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have Grid with 3 columns.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="215"/>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

In first column I have image.
In second Stack Panel.
In third I have my user control and I want to make it horizontal right, but it's  align to left.

This is code for my third column

```
<local:MyControl
Grid.Column="2"
HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Comment: Can you put an image how it looks.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian <Image Grid.Column="0" Source=/Assets/test.png" />

Comment: Very difficult to replicate without an image of what's going wrong, or a skeleton of your `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your user control, you have designed the layout inside a grid, and the alignment of the elements inside the grid (possibly "LayoutRoot") is left, then the control will take up whole of your third column and your control wilol appear as if it is left aligned, even though you have aligned it to the right.

So, even though your control is aligned to the right, the elements inside the control may be aligned to the left and if the "LayoutRoot" of the control is a grid then maybe it is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no width defined for user control hence it will expand to fit all the width that is available in that column.
Note for 3rd Column `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />`